# How to config eslint-loader to lint NPM linked modules?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, eslint, npm-link

I am working on a large JavaScript project that's broken down into a few sub modules, each sub modules have their own git repository and Node dependencies. And we also have an entry point module, `App`, which has Webpack and ESLint configuration.

Since most of the developers would work on a few modules in tandem with each other, instead of waiting for each module is published, we use `npm link` to connect the sub-modules to the App module, so the changes to submodule during development time would be immediately visible to the `App` module.

We have run into issues to get `eslint-loader` to lint not only the `App` module source code, but all the submodules which are linked through `npm link`.  When linting the submodule's code, `eslint-loader` failed to resolve the paths local to the submodule.

Is there a way for me to get around this problem?

Here is a sample structure of the project:

```
--- App
 |    src
 |    node_modules
 |- Sub_module_x
 |    src
 |    node_modules
 |- Sub_module_y
      src
      node_modules
```

Here is the relevant section of eslint-loader in `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: {
    preloaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'eslint-loader',
            exclude: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'Sub_module_x'), // If this is commented, the loader would lint Sub_module_x, but cannot resolve any files which import other files
                /node_modules/
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us where the webpack.config stays and show us the webpack.config?

Comment: The natural way to do this is to lint each module separately. One per package.json.
That approach has many advantages when comparing it to the approach that you're using. For example, if a eslint configuration is present on each project you can, with an IDE plugin, lint files when it's written, so it teachs developers how to do it.
If you do this, then you will have a script on you app entry point that just requires all the script within the submodules and webpack will work naturally as well.

Do you have a constraint again replicating/extending the eslint configuration among projects?

Comment: @nico is right. You should think of those linked modules as npm packages—they're distributable and so they should be self-contained. Your linter doesn't lint the packages you install in node_modules, and it shouldn't. Those packages lint themselves. Your linked modules should behave the same way.

Comment: If you used one repository (like the babel monolithic approach - https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/doc/design/monorepo.md) you could include the package as a symlink dependency (file://./path-to-folder) while keeping the files in the project root for eslint to work once. Babel wrote their own tool (https://github.com/lerna/lerna) for managing this as well because using symlinks has only been an options since npm@5.